# Taking the half-derivative of $e^x$

Tags: calculus, integration, fractional-calculus

While attempting to teach myself the fractional calculus, I encountered a tragically early roadblock. For non-power rule fractional derivatives, I am having a lot of trouble evaluating for a closed form.

Would someone mind walking me through the process for taking the half-derivative of $$f(x) = e^x$$

Really the most difficult part is evaluating

$$\int_0^x \frac{e^t}{\sqrt{x-t}} dt$$

but a full hand-holding would be really helpful.

Comment: I don't think you've written down the integral you actually need help with.  At the very least, it should probably have an $e^t$ in the integrand rather than an $e^x$.

Comment: You're definitely right. I'm sorry!

Comment: Shouldn't the integral involve $\sqrt{x - t}$ rather than $x - t$?

Comment: That's embarrassing. Now I feel bad about making so many mistakes in my first question on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have the right integral now? Because had almost wriiten down the second answer with again the wrong integral.

Comment: Yes. I just double-checked with the general form from my textbook. So sorry.

Comment: Don't worry about it.

Comment: @craft94, you can do "penance" by upvoting the correct answers to the original version of the question, even though they're no longer relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the integral: Keep in mind that $x$ is a constant!

$$\int_0^x \frac{e^t}{\sqrt{x-t}} dt$$

Use the substitution $u=x-t$, then $du=-dt$. This gives:

$$\int_0^x -\frac{e^{x-u}}{\sqrt{u}} du$$

$$-e^x\int_0^x \frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt{u}} du$$

$$-e^x\int_0^x u^{-1/2}e^{-u} du$$

$$-e^x\gamma\left(\frac{1}{2},x\right)$$

Where $\gamma$ is the incomplete lower gamma function.

This can also be written as 
$$-e^x \sqrt{x} E_{\frac{1}{2}}(x)$$

using the exponential integral function. It has been proven there is no closed form of this function.

Comment: So does that mean that the half-derivative doesn't exist? Or is infinite? I really wish there more intuition to be garnered from fractional-calculus.

Comment: @craft94 It means that there is no closed form.

Answer (score 6):

Let we assume that $x>0$. Since:
$$ e^x = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}\tag{1} $$
and:
$$ D^{1/2} x^{m} = \frac{x^{m-1/2}\,\Gamma\!\left(m+1\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\tag{2}$$
(look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Semiderivative.html), for instance) we have:
$$ D^{1/2} e^x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{1+e^x\sqrt{\pi x}\;\text{Erf}(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{\pi x}}\tag{3}$$
where $\text{Erf}$ is the usual [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: Is it clear that fractional derivatives can be computed term-wise?

Answer (score 4):

$${1 \over {\Gamma(1/2)}} \cdot {{d} \over {dx}} \int_0^x {{e^t} \over {\sqrt {x-t}}} \ dt$$
Where $\Gamma(x)$ is the generalized factorial function. This equals
$${1 \over {\Gamma(1/2)}} \cdot {{d} \over {dx}} \int_0^x {{e^t} \over {\sqrt {x-t}}} \ dt=e^x \cdot \operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{x})$$
where $\operatorname{erf}(u)$ is the [error function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=erf%28x%29&lk=4). This is more of a definition than a technical thing, so you don't really need to prove the above per se. However the substitution $u=\sqrt{x-t}$ and integration by parts brings the above into compliance with
$$\operatorname{erf}(x)={2 \over {\sqrt{\pi}}} \cdot \int_0^x e^{-t^2} \ dt$$

Answer (score 1):

If this is really the integral you want, then notice you are integrating with respect to $t$ so treat $x$ as a constant. Then $$\int \frac{e^x}{x-t} dt = e^x\int\frac{1}{x-t} dt$$ and the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x-t}$ with respect to $t$ is easily seen to be $-\ln(x-t)+C$. Now evaluate the integral as you normally would with a definite integral.

Comment: Just a note, for anyone who comes along 6 years later as I did:  this is a response to the original version of this question (see [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322857/taking-the-half-derivative-of-ex#comment2687802_1322857) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322857/taking-the-half-derivative-of-ex#comment2687811_1322857)).

Answer (score -1):

This depends on a method and definition used, but all the other answers give unnatural expressions in my view.

The following definitions give a more natural answer and coincide with each other.

The first one is based on Newton series interpolation over consecutive integer derivatives:

$$f^{(s)}(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom {s}m \sum_{k=0}^m\binom mk(-1)^{m-k}f^{(k)}(x)$$

the other one is based on Forier transform:

$$f^{(s)}(x)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{- i \omega x}{\omega}^s \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{i\omega t}dt \, d\omega$$

For $f(x)=e^x$ they both give the same result: the derivative of any order of this function is $e^x$. In other words, this function is invariant regarding differentiation and integration of any order.