# Solutions to this fractional differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, fractional-calculus, fractional-differential-equations

So we all know that $\frac d{dx}e^x=e^x$ and that the $n$th derivative of $e^x$ is still $e^x$, but upon entering fractional calculus, this is ruined.  Let $D^\alpha$ be the $\alpha$th derivative with respect to $x$.  Then, [as we can see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322857/taking-the-half-derivative-of-ex), when $\alpha\in[0,1)$,

$$D^\alpha e^x=-\frac1{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}e^x\gamma(\alpha,x)\ne e^x$$

where we use the lower incomplete gamma function.

Which raises the interesting question:

> What are the solutions to the following fractional differential equation? $$D^\alpha f(x)=f(x)$$

where we have

$$D^\alpha f(x)=\frac1{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}\int_0^x\frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{(x-t)^{\alpha+1-n}}\ dt$$

with $n=\lfloor\alpha+1\rfloor$.

---

$f$ may be a function of $\alpha$.

Comment: This does of course depend on the differintegral used: with the fixed limit $a=-\infty$, you *do* get $D_{-\infty}^{\alpha}e^{x} = e^{x}$

Comment: @Chappers Yes, but I have given the differintegral I want to use for this problem.

Comment: @LowGPA It's the well-known [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: I guess $\gamma$ denotes  Euler–Mascheroni constant?

Comment: @LowGPA It's the lower incomplete gamma function.  See the link in the first paragraph.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Do you really want to stick to this precise definition of fractional differential operators (it's not really used in the higher circles of mathematics), or do you accept instead the one based upon the Fourier transform, that leads to Hörmander's theory of pseudo-differential operators? In the latter case, the answer to your problem would be given by a simple Fourier transform.

Comment: @AlexM. I think I'll stick with this one.  If I want to consider another definition, I'll ask it as another question :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first part is not a strict answer to the question, but not far. The full answer is added in second part.

Consider the series expansion :
$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\Gamma(k+1)} \qquad |x|<1$$

Compare to the Mittag-Leffler function :
$$E_\alpha(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\Gamma(\alpha k+1)}$$
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mittag-LefflerFunction.html
$$\text{Or }\qquad E_\alpha(x^\alpha)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha k}}{\Gamma(\alpha k+1)}$$

This function matches the exponential function in particular case $\alpha=1$.

It is of interest to see what is the fractional derivative of $\left(E_\alpha(x^\alpha)-1\right)$. We will see latter why the first term of the series is considered apart.
$$\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}\left(E_\alpha(x^\alpha)-1\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha k+1)}\frac{d^\alpha }{dx^\alpha}(x^{\alpha k})$$
$\frac{d^\alpha }{dx^\alpha}(x^{\alpha k})=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha k+1)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha (k-1)+1\right)}x^{\alpha(k-1)}$

$$\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}\left(E_\alpha(x^\alpha)-1\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha k+1)}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha k+1)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha (k-1)+1\right)}x^{\alpha(k-1)}$$

$$\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}\left(E_\alpha(x^\alpha)-1\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha(k-1)}}{\Gamma\left(\alpha (k-1)+1\right)}=\sum_{h=0}^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha h}}{\Gamma\left(\alpha h+1\right)}$$

$$\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}\left(E_\alpha(x^\alpha)-1\right)=E_\alpha(x^\alpha)$$

$$\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}E_\alpha(x^\alpha)=E_\alpha(x^\alpha)+\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}(1)$$

This is close to the expected equation
$$\quad \frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}f(x)=f(x)\qquad \text{with} \quad f(x)=E_\alpha(x^\alpha)$$
But there is an extra term $\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}(1)=\frac{x^{-\alpha}}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}$

This is the difference compared to the case $\alpha=1$ of the exponential :
$$\frac{d^1}{dx^1}e^x=e^x+\frac{d^1}{dx^1}(1)=e^x$$
The first term in the series expansion of $e^x$ is constant$=1$. So its derivative is $0$, which is not the case for the fractional derivative of order different from $1$.

In fact, this difference comes from the definition of the lower bound $=0$ in the Riemann-Liouville operator for fractional differ-integration.

IN ADDITION :

In order to have a full solution, the Mittag-Leffler function has to be extended. Instead to limit the series to the terms with $k\geq 0$ consider all terms from $k=-\infty$ to $+\infty$.
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha k}}{\Gamma(\alpha k+1)}$$
The same calculus as above shows that $f(x)$ is a formal solution of the fractional differential equation
$$\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}f(x)=f(x)$$

Note :

Also, this is valid for the exponential function and $\alpha=1$ since $$\quad \frac{1}{k!}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(k+1)}=0 \quad\text{in}\quad k<0 \quad\to\quad e^x=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} $$ .

Comment: Your double sum does not converge for $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{Z}$, as the reflection formula $$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\pi\csc(\pi x)$$ guarantees the terms will blow up in magnitude to $\infty$ as either $k\rightarrow \infty$ or $k\rightarrow -\infty$

Answer (score 0):

This is a (heuristic) answer for $\alpha=1/k$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$. And assuming $Df$ exists. Note that
I believe (see edit in the end) that we could extend this answer to any $\alpha$.

Let $\alpha = 1/2$. Then, by definition of the fractional derivative, we have
$$D^\alpha D^\alpha f = Df$$
Substituting on the LHS what the differential equation implies we obtain
$$D^\alpha f = D f$$

More general,
$$D^{(k-1)\alpha}f=D f \quad (*)$$

I can only think of the function $f\equiv 0$ which satisfies this and the given differential equation.

**Edit:** We could continue with equation $(*)$ by plugging in repetedly the diff eq on the LHS to obtain
$$ D^{(k-2)\alpha}f=D f$$
$$ D^{(k-3)\alpha}f=D f$$
$$\ldots$$
 $$ f=D f$$
Since we know two solutions for the very last equation and since one of them does not satisfy the fract diff eq given in the question, we conclude that indeed $f\equiv 0$ is the only soluton.

I believe that this is also true for any $\alpha$ if we assume that $f$ has a derivative up to a certain order: Start with rational $\alpha=p/q$ then start the argument with $ (D^\alpha)^q f$.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that $f$ could be a function of $\alpha$, or else I think $f=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt do you mean $x=g(\alpha)$ for some $g$? But doesn't that cause troubles for the definition of the fract derivative? For example would $D^{1/3}D^{2/3}f=Df$ still hold?

Comment: No, I mean the solution should be of the form $f_\alpha(x)$, a function depending on both $\alpha$ and $x$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt so the fract diff eq would be $D^\alpha f_\alpha = f_0$ where the RHS is explained by $f=D^0 f$? If so, I do not see the meaning of this. If it is not this, I do not see why my answer wouldn't cover that case....I didn't forbid $f$ to have a parameter equal to $\alpha$ in my derivations....

Comment: No, it would be $D^\alpha f_\alpha(x)=f_\alpha(x)$.

Comment: So these are separate solutions for each $\alpha$, so I don't see how your answer still applies.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt well, take $\alpha = 1/2$. Suppose there is a solution $f_\alpha$ different from zero function. This means $D^\alpha f_\alpha= f_\alpha$. But then we must also have (argument from my answer) $D^1 f_\alpha= f_\alpha $. Isn't this a contradiction?! The same solution for two different equations?

Answer (score -1):

IDK if $\alpha<1$

For special cases of $\alpha >1$,

$f^\alpha=f$ gives:

$f=\sum_{k\leq\alpha} C_ke^{e^{\frac{{2ki\pi}}{\alpha}}x}+\sum_{n\leq\alpha} C_ne^{e^{\frac{{2i\pi}}{n}}x}$
where $k,n\in\mathbb{N}^*$

Comment: Only for $\alpha\in\mathbb N$.  $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ behaves much differently.

Comment: This is for $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: No... I can assure you its not.  It already fails $\alpha=1/2$.  See the link in the first paragraph of my post.

Comment: Did I not mention "IDK if $\alpha<1$" "for $\alpha>1$"?

Comment: Oh, my bad.  But it follows directly that this would fail for $\alpha=3/2$ then.