# Solving Differential Equations using Fractional Calculus

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

Are there any integer order differential equations or integral equations that can be solved using fractional calculus?
For example, the Abel's Integral (like from the Tautochrone Problem):
$$\int_{0}^{h}\dfrac{u(y)}{\sqrt{h-y}}dy=C$$
where $C$ is a constant. Given the Riemann-Liouville Integral:
$$I^{\alpha}f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int f(t)(x-t)^{\alpha-1}dt$$
This problem can easily be solved by representing the integral by the half integral of $u(y)$
and taing the half derivative on both sides.

Are there any other such differential equations that can be solved using fractional calculus?

Comment: You showed an example of an integral, not differential, equation.

Comment: Fractional differential equations are differential equations which, among other things, can be solved using fractional calculus, [e.g. $\left[D^{1.5}-D^{0}\right]\cdot y\left(x\right)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304841/solve-fde-f1-5x-fx).You can also solve differential equations with derivatives that do not have an explicit number as order but an unknown constant, [e.g. $\left[D^{2v}+\alpha D^{v}+\beta D^{0}\right]\cdot y\left(x\right)=0$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDifferentialEquation.html) with fractional calculus. Do you mean something like that?

Comment: @KevinDietrich I am more interested in whether there any such results using fractional calculus to solve ordinary order differential or integral equations. Are there any other examples of where this can be used?